# Gem server not serving gemspec.rz

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've setup a local gem server for my group on the internal network, and it serves most gems fine, except annotate which needs the gemspec.rz and my server returns a 404 every time it hits it.
I do have the annotate gem installed on the gem server with its quick/marshal/gemspec under specifications, I even manually setup a quick/marshal in the "root" dir, nothing works.

When I do gem generate_index it simply wipes the quick/marshal dir

When I do a bundle install from a dev machine with the local gem server (x.x.x.x) as source, this is what I get

```
Fetching source index from http://x.x.x.x:8808/
Resolving dependencies...

Net::HTTPNotFound: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE></HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <H1>Not Found</H1>
    `/quick/Marshal.4.8/annotate-2.4.1.beta1.gemspec.rz' not found.
    <HR>
    <ADDRESS>
     WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2013-11-22) at
     x.x.x.x:8808
    </ADDRESS>
  </BODY>
</HTML>


# wget http://x.x.x.x:8808/quick/Marshal.4.8/annotate-2.4.1.beta1.gemspec.rz
--2014-02-07 14:53:12--  http://x.x.x.x:8808/quick/Marshal.4.8/annotate-2.4.1.beta1.gemspec.rz
Connecting to x.x.x.x:8808... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-02-07 14:53:12 ERROR 404: Not Found.


# wget http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/annotate-2.4.1.beta1.gemspec.rz
--2014-02-07 14:54:20--  http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/annotate-2.4.1.beta1.gemspec.rz
Location: http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/annotate-2.4.1.beta1.gemspec.rz [following]
--2014-02-07 14:54:20--  http://production.cf.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/annotate-2.4.1.beta1.gemspec.rz
Length: 471 [binary/octet-stream]
Saving to: “annotate-2.4.1.beta1.gemspec.rz”

2014-02-07 14:54:21 (48.0 MB/s) - “annotate-2.4.1.beta1.gemspec.rz” saved [471/471]
```

Comment: why are you accessing `quick/Marshal.4.8` that looks like an internal url. are you sure that you don't get a redirect?

Comment: @phoet it is an internal ip, it's the local gem server I've set up. I get that when I do bundle install and it tries to install annotate. You can see there's a redirect on the rubygems.org, but I don't see why my gem server doesn't serve the file it has

Comment: make sure that route routes are setup correctly, which app have you use to give the file?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I'm using the gem server, didn't know you could configure routes for that specifically ? Rails isn't running on this machine

Comment: Yes, rails may not be runned, but with app answer on `http://x.x.x.x:8808/`?

Comment: That's the gem server up on x.x.x.x, sorry for the confusion. I'll update the question

Comment: @Blackbird57 did you ever solve this? we have the same problem with another gem (sporc) on 6 different machines

Comment: @rmcsharry no I never did. The thing is that the rz file is on the server in the right directory, it's just not being served for some reason. I don't know if you have the same problem

Comment: @Blackbird57 yep, same problem. rz file is also on the server in the right directory. Still not resolved :(